# Angular modal-backdrop issue

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, modalpopups

I am using `angular-bootstrap` modal but I have an issue with modal-backdrop. I am new to `angular-bootstrap`, and I hope anyone can help me.

When I click on modal-backdrop it's hiding the modal popup, but I would like to keep the modal-backdrop until click cancel.

[modal popup code is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YPESA3?p=preview)

any one please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: Just a note that this is clearly explained in [our documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).  Look at the `backdrop` option.  Additionally, we have working plunker examples which which you can play with the options to see how they work prior to using them in your application.  Please extend us and the community the courtesy of reading the documentation before asking for help.

Answer (score 14):

If you use the Angular UI Bootstrap [modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) you can set `backdrop` to `static` (→ backdrop is present but modal window is not closed when clicking outside of the modal window):

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  backdrop: 'static',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UZe51abrHBnwoyaJzIYm?p=preview).

Comment: I want this to work on IE browsers already i tried with static but IE browsers not working

Comment: Thanks! Had no clue how to fix this!

Answer (score 4):

There are main two property backdrop and keyboard in every model window.

- **Backdrop property**
  In you can set two property
       backdrop = 'static'
            Clicking outside of model window,model window will not get closed with background **will be grayed out**.
       backdrop  = 'false'
            Clicking outside of model window,model window will not get closed but background **will not be grayed out**.
       backdrop = 'true'
            Clicking outside window, model window will get closed.
- **keyboard property**
      keyboard = 'false'
            By pressing esc key model window will not get closed.
      keyboard = 'true'
            By pressing esc key model window will get closed.